# PHP variable used in <script> code is being added to URL

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Javascript API in a PHP page and want to use values received by the user through PHP (basically, user inputted addresses) to be used in the map JS code. My code is roughly set as below:

```
<?php $myVar = "new york"; ?>

<script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDwKLaKFqCqNs61pylmB8Yqj6I0v1LhE-A">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var latitude, longitude;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var location = <?php echo json_encode($myVar); ?>;

geocoder.geocode({ "address": location}, function(results, status){
    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
});

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
        zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                  mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

However, everytime I try to run this, the string "new york" just gets added to my URL, like so:

```
http://localhost:8888/quill/shows/the-merchant-of-venice/new%20york
```

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code is at top level, your variable `location` is actually `window.location`, which is used to set the URL of the page.

Put all your Javascript code inside an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) to give it its own variable scope:

```
(function() {
    var latitude, longitude;

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var location = <?php echo json_encode($myVar); ?>;

    geocoder.geocode({ "address": location}, function(results, status){
        latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    });

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
            zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                      mapOptions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
})();
```

Comment: ahhhhh, wow I didn't even realize I was using location as the variable name. So stupid of me...thank you very much for the clarification.